# invalid quotes in find call

Tags: cakephp

In my project
`

```
$cid = $this->Surgical->find('first',array('conditions' => 
 array('to_char(dt_surgery , \'DD-MM-YYYY\' )' =>'to_char(now() ,\'DD-MM-YYYY\')')));
```

In debug mode the query equals the following:=

SELECT "Surgical"."id"   FROM "surgicals" AS "Surgical"   WHERE to_char(dt_surgery , 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) = **'to_char(now() ,''DD-MM-YYYY'')'**  LIMIT 1

My problem is unwanted quotes at 'to_char(now() ,''DD-MM-YYYY'')' i.e at begin and at end. Also there is double quotes at  ''DD-MM-YYYY''

My db is Postgres and cake version is 1.3.
Actually I want the following 'where' condition inside the select query

```
WHERE to_char(dt_surgery , 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) = to_char(now() ,'DD-MM-YYYY') LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this? Notice line 3 does not have `' => '` but just `=`

```
$cid = $this->Surgical->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'to_char(dt_surgery , \'DD-MM-YYYY\') = to_char(now() ,\'DD-MM-YYYY\')'
     )
 ));
```